# Writing a setup script that only runs a command if directory hasn't been modified for 1 day

Tags: bash, scripting

I've got a shell script that performs some tasks using files from a Subversion repository. I would like the Subversion repository to keep up-to-date, but right now the script runs `svn up` every time which is annoying if I need to run the script several times in a row.

Since `svn up` changes the last modified timestamp of the `.svn` directory (even if there were no new commits), I figured that I could use that to make sure it only runs `svn up` once per day or so.

I tried finding a simple way of just checking whether the `.svn` directory is older than a day, but there were many seemingly overkill ways of doing it so I thought I'd ask here in case there's actually a very simple way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is somewhat simple:

```
[ `find /path/to/.svn -maxdepth 0 -mtime +1 | wc -l` -gt 1 ] && svn up
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing the big picture here, but can't you just run a once-daily cron job to update the svn repository?

e.g.

crontab -e

then add a

```
4 * * * /root/updatecron.sh
```

where updatecron.sh contains

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /my/directory
/usr/bin/svn up
```

or something like that?

Comment: The idea is that the directory that has this script is self-contained. I'd rather not set up cron jobs since it's part of an open source project. So deleting the directory of the project should mean it's completely gone.